# Can anyone tell me why eclipse doesn't like this java array initialisation ?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to using eclipse and I am totally puzzled as to why it doesn't like the first line of my for loop

```
public Practice(int n) {
    this.n=n;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            this.decay=new double[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What is it?

Comment: When your code has major syntax errors, Eclipse does have a tendency to sometimes put red cross signs and squiggles somewhere **above** where the actual syntax error occurs.

Comment: yeah this is confusing. I had not noticed it before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the `for` keyword for the second loop.  Corrected:

```
public Practice(int n) {
    this.n=n;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            this.decay=new double[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You're using a parenthesis not a curly brace.

Edit - Sorry, didn't look at the way you formatted it.